# Processing and replacing text inside double curly braces

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a URL string:

`var url = https://url.com/{{query}}/foo/{{query2}}`

I have a line of code that is able to take in a string, then get an array of all the queries inside the braces:

`var queries = String(url).match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g);`

Returns:
`queries = ['query', 'query2']`

I have a function, `parse(queries)`, which processes these queries and returns a list of their results:

`results = ['resultOfQuery', 'resultOfQuery2']`

I want to be able to take this list, and then replace the queries in the URL string with their results. The final result of this example would be:

`url = https://url.com/resultOfQuery/foo/resultOfQuery2`

I have two separate problems:

1. The regex in the `String.match` line of code only counts for once set of curly braces, `{something}`. How can I modify it to look for a set of double curly braces, {{something}}?
2. I already have the array of results. What is the best way to do the string replacement so that the queries and each of their accompanying set of double braces are replaced with their corresponding result?

Comment: Try `var result = s.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function($0,$1) { return parse($1); } )`, but your `parse` function should be able to accept a single string as argument.

Comment: What constraints are there on the format of the string between `{{ ... }}`? E.g. will it always be a valid JS variable name?

Comment: The string in between `{{ }}` can be any string. My `parse()` function does all the potential error handling. It could be `{{foo}}` if the user was so inclined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use replace with following pattern,

```
{{(.+?)}}
```

- `{{` - Matches `{{`
- `(.+?)` - Matches anything except newline one or more time

```js
let url = "https://url.com/{{query}}/foo/{{query2}}"

let result = {'query': 'queryResult1', 'query2':'queryResult2' }

let replaceDoubleBraces = (str,result) =>{
  return str.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, (_,g1) => result[g1] || g1)
}

console.log(replaceDoubleBraces(url,result))
```

Note:- I am using result as object here so it becomes easy to find and replace values, if you can change your parse function consider returning an object from parse

Comment: The only downside here would be if a single `}` is allowed to appear within the `{{ ... }}` construct. For example, `var url = https://url.com/{{very}weird}indeed}}/foo/`.

Comment: @GershomMaes updated, IMO it should be constrain to keep thing consistent

Comment: I agree, I don't see a need to allow complex terms inside the `{{ ... }}` templates!

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is a working solution. Even if there were brackets inside the `query`, I'm leaving the onus on the user to figure out their own syntax errors/bugs

Comment: @CodeManiac quick follow up for a different problem - if I use `str.match(/{{(.+?)}}/g)`, that will return an array *with* the double braces, ie. `['{{query}}']`. Is there a regex that will only return a query itself, `['query']` ?

Comment: @erli you should edit your question accordingly, if it is very much different form this question form a new question mate,

Answer (score 1):

Generalized solution which will also work with nested object.

```
function replaceText(text, obj, start = '{{', end = '}}') {
  return text.replace(new RegExp(`${start}(.+?)${end}`, 'g'), (_, part) => {
    return part.split('.')
      .reduce((o, k) => (
        o || {}
      )[k], obj);
  });
}

console.log(replaceText(
  'Hello my name is {{name.first}} {{name.last}}, age: {{age}}',
  {
    name: {
      first: 'first', last: 'last'
    },
    age: 20,
  }
));
```

To use Regex inbuild symbols as template, use double backslash `\\` before each character. It is because above function uses template string `new RegExp('\\^(.+?)\\^', 'g')` to create regular expression instead RegExp constructor `new RegExp(/\^(.+?)\^/g)`, otherwise single backslash is enough.
For example

```
(  => \\(
)  => \\)
(( => \\(\\(
)) => \\)\\)
^  => \\^
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to do it:

```js
const string = "Hello {{world}}";

console.log(string.replace(/{{.*}}/, "Stack Overflow"));
```